# Choose between colors using a switch case paintcomponent (values from dropdown)

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, colors, switch-statement, paintcomponent

As an assignment for school I need to draw an appeltree with apples using `paintcomponent` in java. The user must be able to choose a color from a dropdown and this will change the color of the apples.

Now that's where I'm stuck. I tried creating the colors in a switch case, but this results into some errors.

What you see below isn't the whole code, just the parts that is necessary for the apples. 
I think for some reason java doesn't execute the switch case.

Thanks in advance!

```
// get the values from the dropbox
private void jComboBoxKleurActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                               
   appel = (String)jComboBoxKleur.getSelectedItem();
   repaint();
}

// create the colors for the apples (kleur means color in dutch & appel means apple in     dutch)
switch (appel){
   case "Gifgroen":
      Color kleur = new Color(184, 208, 68);
      break;
   case "Rood":
      Color kleur = new Color(142, 41, 13);
      break;
   case "Geelgroen":
      Color kleur = new Color(215, 255, 1);
      break;
   default:
      Color kleur = new Color(142, 41, 13);
      break;
    }


     //draw the apples
     g.setColor(kleur);
     g.fillOval(30, 650, 40, 40);
     g.setColor(Color.black);
     g.fillRect(50, 640, 5, 10);
```

Comment: does this compile? Would be strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you are not saying anything about the bunch of error you are having: i can easily assume that, first thing it is saying:

Variable `kleur` is already defined: yes, because, you have already declared kleur in your first `case` and it belongs to the block of `switch`. Any subsequent declaration of `kleur` is unnecessary.
 remove the `Color`  from `Color kleur` inside the `case` statement. Rather declare your `Color kleur` once outside of the `switch` block.

```
    Color kleur;  // <--- here declaring it

    switch (appel){
    case "Gifgroen":
        kleur = new Color(184, 208, 68); // ere initializing it if needed
        break;
    case "Rood":
        kleur = new Color(142, 41, 13);
        break;
    // other cases 
    default:
        kleur = new Color(142, 41, 13);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thank's it worked! I didn't post the errors  beacuse i thought an explanation of the problem was more clear, anyhow you understood what i meant and the problem was fixed. Thanks for your time and effort